# About AttachConsole/Freeconsole API function

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, command-line, cmd

When I attach the parent CMD to my app, after releasing the attached CMD using **Freeconsole**, there is an empty line in CMD where I can write... is like an "**@Echo OFF**", when I press "ENTER" returns the echo (**@Echo ON**).

http://img607.imageshack.us/img607/566/captura1em.png

this is a VB code to give an example:

```
Private Sub Parse_Arguments()
    AttachConsole(-1)
    For I As Integer = 0 To My.Application.CommandLineArgs.Count - 1
        If My.Application.CommandLineArgs.Item(I) = "/?" Then
            Dim Logo As String = <a><![CDATA[Blah blah blah...]]></a>.Value
            Console.WriteLine(Logo)
            FreeConsole()
            End
        End If
    Next
end sub
```

I hope do you know what I'm trying to say, I need the CMD to be fully verbose, I mean I want the CMD to print the last line "**C:\Visual Studio Projects\Aero Switcher\Aero Switch\bin\Debug>**" when releasing the attached CMD (when my program finishes the execution), and not to printing a empty line without "echo".

Another example:

**This is what I Want:**

```
C:\>Process.exe
C:\>Text wrote from the process and process finished
c:\>Verbose CMD line, "c:\>" is shown, @Echo is ON, all good!.
```

**This is what I get:**

```
C:\>Process.exe
C:\>Text wrote from the process and process finished
Damn empty line where I can write commands, not verbose line, @Echo is OFF.
C:\>Verbose CMD line.
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the link target of your application to a console app?  That should give you perfect console integration, but will not prevent you from opening a Window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An old question, but one I was struggling with this myself, so I thought I would post my findings...

After spending a lot of time on this, I came to the conclusion that I was looking at it completely wrong.

The Current Directory is listed immediately after the call to your executable - your first Console.WriteLine() will be on the same line as this.

After the call to `FreeConsole()` we are back at the console. The fact that the line is blank is almost irrelevant - the CMD prompt **did** show the current directory, but it appears **before** all of your application output. If you want to make it look like the user is back at a *"normal"* console then simply output the current directory before the call to `FreeConsole()`:

```
Console.Write(FileIO.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & ">")
```

This does feel like a hack, but with the way attaching to a console process works, it's probably all you can do.

Comment: Nitpicking: Note that the prompt format is not always `_currentdir_>`. It is determined by the content of the "PROMPT" environment variable (see `help prompt` when in a console window.) So "properly" mimicing it is much more involved (not to speek of when you execute from inside PowerShell or other intepreters).

Comment: @Christian.K - Good point! It most certainly doesn't look right running from a Git bash shell! In my case it doesn't matter so much - it's a program to be used internally by support staff, we just happen to have some (older) employees that prefer working in a command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

After your `FreeConsole()` add `SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}")` and it will all work in the way that you wanted.

```
Console.WriteLine(Logo)
FreeConsole()
SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}")
```